# Can you own more than 20 vehicles?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I recently bought another 10 car garage aside from my apartment, which also has a 10 car garage. And this may be stupid, but can you own more than that?

Answer (score 3):

Currently you can buy three houses / garages, for a maximum of 30 cars, not including Pegasus vehicles.